# Get response error "This list already exists. You need to enter a different name."

Tags: getresponse

I am using [GetResponse](https://www.getresponse.com/) and trying to create a new list and seeing [this error](http://prntscr.com/qmydii) :

> This list already exists. You need to enter a different name.

But I have not created any list with this name. So how is it possible?
Is `GetResponse` checking its entire database on lists created by the same name ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GetResponse checks it's entire DataBase.
From the GetResponse Docs:

> **Please remember that the name must be unique – it can’t exist in any GetResponse account. The name must be between 3-64 characters (only lowercase a-z, numbers, minus (-), and underscore (_).**